# Purpose of tilde in JSON Pointer

Tags: json, json-patch, jsonpointer

The [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) spec states:

> the characters '~' (%x7E) and '/' (%x2F) have special    meanings in
> JSON Pointer

It is clear what '/' is used for, but I see no indication of what purpose the tilde serves (only mention that it needs to be escaped and how).

Comment: Related: [How is the tilde escaping in the JSON Patch RFC supposed to operate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24419391/477563)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In JSON Pointer, you need to use `~1` to encode that you want to have `/` as part of the property name in the path. Because of that, `~` gets the special meaning as an indicator of the escape sequence an no longer expresses a real tilde. The real tilde is expressed as an escape sequence `~0`.

In other words (quote from JSON Pointer spec):

> Evaluation of each reference token begins by decoding any escaped
>      character sequence.  This is performed by first transforming any
>      occurrence of the sequence '~1' to '/', and then transforming any
>      occurrence of the sequence '~0' to '~'.  By performing the
>      substitutions in this order, an implementation avoids the error of
>      turning '~01' first into '~1' and then into '/', which would be
>      incorrect (the string '~01' correctly becomes '~1' after
>      transformation).

It might be interesting to take a look at JSON Patch tests here: https://github.com/json-patch/json-patch-tests/blob/master/spec_tests.json#L200 (search for `~`)

Comment: Ah, sorry, feel dumb now. I guess I'm just too used to syntaxes where escape characters otherwise have their own actual special function outside of escaping.